# Finding the Gap Numbers in a list

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, linq, t-sql

I am writing an application in c# , visual studio 2010
I have data like the following

```
Id  tagNo TermNo
1    1000   2
2    1000   3
3    1000   7
4    1002   1
5    1002   10
```

how can i get the following result via the linq or tsql

```
tagNo   TermNo
1000    1,4,5,6
1002    2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
```

Thank you

Comment: I follow. Why is this being down voted?  OP wants integers 1 or greater not in TermNo and less than maximum value in TermNo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like the following:

```
var openTags =
    from item in source                           // Take the source items
    group item by item.tagNo into g               // and group them by their tagNo.
    let inUse = g.Select(_ => _.TermNo)           // Find all of the in-use tags
    let max = inUse.Max()                         // and max of that collection.
    let range = Enumerable.Range(1, max - 1)      // Construct the range [1, max)
    select new
    {                               // Select the following
       TagNo = g.Key                // for each group
       TermNo = range.Except(inUse) // find the available tags
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by using linq,

```
var tagsList = sourceLists.Select(t => t.TagNo).Distinct().ToList();
foreach (var tagList in tagsList)
{
var terminalList = sourceLists.Where(t => t.TagNo == tagList).Select(t => int.Parse(t.TermNo)).ToList();    
var result = Enumerable.Range(1, terminalList.Max()).Except(terminalList).ToList();
}
```

but can anybody tell me if it is possible in TSQL or not
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

One hint to do it using oracle is as follows- (You can achieve it in TSQL also)

```
SELECT COLUMN_VALUE 
FROM TABLE(SYS.DBMS_DEBUG_VC2COLL(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10))
MINUS
SELECT '4'
FROM DUAL;
```

This will filter out '4' from the provided list. (1 to 10)
Similarly, you can filter out your items (2,3,7,1,10) *Provided, you need to write your query*

Comment: question is tagged TSQL and your solution will not work anyway. It will work for 1 row only

Answer (score 0):

*Assuming* `sourceLists` is actually an EF entity, the following should execute all on the DB

```
var terminalsByTag = sourceLists.GroupBy(x => x.TagNo)
                                .Select(x => new {
                                    TagNo = x.Key,
                                    Terminals = x.Select(t => Int32.Parse(t.TermNo))
                                });
var result = Enumerable.Range(1, terminalsByTag.Max(g => g.Terminals.Max()).Except(g => g.Terminals).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a TSQL solution as you requested(corrected):

```
declare @t table(Id int, tagNo int, TermNo int)
insert @t values
(1,1000,2), (2,1000,3), (3,1000,7), (4,1002,1), (5,1002,10)

;with a as
(
  select max(TermNo)-1 MaxTermNo, TagNo
  from @t 
  group by TagNo
),
b as
(
  select 1 TermNo, TagNo, MaxTermNo
  from a
  union all
  select TermNo+1, TagNo, MaxTermNo
  from b 
  where TermNo < MaxTermNo
), 
c as
(
  select TermNo, TagNo 
  from b
  except 
  select TermNo, TagNo
  from @t
)
select t.TagNo 
    ,STUFF(( 
        select ',' + cast(TermNo as varchar(9))
        from c t1 
        where t1.TagNo = t.TagNo
        order by TermNo
        for xml path(''), type 
    ).value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 1, '') TermNo 
from c t 
group by t.TagNo 
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

Result:

```
TagNo   TermNo
1000    1,4,5,6
1002    2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
```